# Why doesnt Elasticsearch match any number in keyphrase?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching for the following keyphrase: "xiaomi redmi note 3" in my Elasticsearch database. I m making the following bool query:

```
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "name" : {
          "query" : "xiaomi redmi note 3",
          "type" : "boolean",
          "operator" : "AND"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, no matches are found. Still in Elasticsearch there is the following document:

```
xiaomi redmi note 3 16GB 4G Phablet
```

Why doesnt es match this document?

What I noticed in general is that es doesnt match any numbers in the keyprhase? Does it have to do with the analyzer I m using?

EDIT

```
"analyzer": {
        "second": {
            "type":      "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter":   [
                "lowercase",
                "trim",
                "autocomplete_filter"
            ]
        },
```

and the mapping for my field is:

```
"name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index_analyzer" : "second",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            },
            "search_quote_analyzer" : "second"
          },
```

Autocomplete_filter:

```
   "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type":     "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 10
    }
```

Comment: what analyzers You used for that field?
It might be, that index analyzer isn't lowercasing so eg xiaomi != XIAOMI

Comment: not really, I m using the lowercase filter. Please see the edits,

Comment: And def for autocomplete_filter is? Because if it's ngram starting from 2 or more then search_analyzer is passing "3" to search, but in the index 3 is removed by ngram ...

Comment: I see, you re right!! I added the def for the filter. thnx Barat

Comment: You can add another field to "fields" like "second" with type "string" and analyzer and search_analyzer as "second" and then search in "name.second" for this, and "name" for autocomplete